# How to change default of function parameter for an instance of an object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

If I have the object

```
>>> class example_class():
>>>    def example_function(number, text = 'I print this: '):
>>>        print text, number
```

I can change the example_function input parameter

```
>>> example_instance = example_class()
>>> print example_instace.example_function(3, text = 'I print that: ')
```

Now I would like to always use `I print that:` every time I use `example_instace`. Is it possible to change the default value of `text` so that I get this behavior:

```
>>> example_instace = example_class()
>>> print example_instance.example_function(3)
I print this: 3
>>> default_value(example_instance.text, 'I print that: ')
>>> print example_instance.example_function(3)
I print that: 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function defaults are stored with the function, and the function object is used to create the method wrapper. You cannot alter that default on a per-instance basis.

Instead, use a sentinel to detect that the default has been picked; `None` is a common sentinel suitable for when `None` itself isn't a valid value:

```
class example_class():
    _example_text_default = 'I print this: '
    def example_function(self, number, text=None):
        if text is None:
            text = self._example_text_default
        print text, number
```

and then simply set `self._example_text_default` on a per-instance basis to override.

If `None` is not a suitable sentinel, create a unique singleton object for the job:

```
_sentinel = object()

class example_class():
    _example_text_default = 'I print this: '
    def example_function(self, number, text=_sentinel):
        if text is _sentinel:
            text = self._example_text_default
        print text, number
```

and now you can use `example_class().example_function(42, None)` as a valid non-default value.