# Using instance variable in Python class function definition

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, recursion

How can I set the default value in the class definition to one of the class' instance variable?

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def do_something(self, data_file=self.data):  # Here

        # modify the data and return to itself using recursion.
        if something:
            return self.do_something(data_file)
        else:
            return data_file
```

Comment: Function defaults are determined *once*, when the function is created. They are not created each time the method is called.

Comment: *"I want to use recursion so I can't access the value inside the function"* - it's not clear why you think those two things go together.

Comment: Another duplicate: [How to change default of function parameter for an instance of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32013733)

Comment: Jonrsharpe link me to a question that is also marked as duplicate.

Comment: @Red2awn: yes, and so did I. There is a canonical there but both jon and I provided more context.

Comment: @Red2awn also the fact that we could do so suggests you hadn't done much looking yourself...

Answer (score 1):

Use another value, and check for it:

```
def do_something(self, data_file=None):
    if data_file is None:
        data_file = self.data

    ...etc...
```